# Soap requests get sluggish

Tags: networking, vmware, vim, sdk

I'm using VMware's Perl SDK 6.7 on an Ubuntu 18.04.  The SDK makes a soap requests to a vcenter server.

We used to be on Ubuntu 14 but moved to 18, and with the same SDK code, a `Vim::connect()` call takes less than a second, which is the expected runtime, but only for the first 10 function calls.

The eleventh and every subsequent call after that takes around 3 minutes each!

I can't find much info on the internet. What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Was the move from Ubuntu 14 to Ubuntu 18 by an upgrade or by reinstallation?

Comment: It wasn't upgraded.  It was a new installation.

Comment: And its a virtual machine, not a physical host.  It was a fresh deploy from an 18.04 template.